# cudaMemPrefetchAsync bug on GTX 1080 (Pascal)?

Tags: cuda, nvidia

On my machine the call to cudeMemPrefetchAsync in the code below returns 10 (cuda error invalid device) rather than 0.  The setup is an Alienware 17 laptop running Windows 10 with a NVidia GTX 1080 GPU and onboard Intel HD Graphics 530. Using driver 376.19 from NVidia (mobile driver)).

I've compiled for compute_61, sm_61.  Another user tried running the same code on a Pascal architecture (Titan X) and it returned 0 correctly.  I've also tested this in both Debug and Release mode with the same result. Any ideas?

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

int main()
{
    int* data;
    size_t len = 10;
    cudaError_t err = cudaSetDevice(0);
    err = cudaMallocManaged(reinterpret_cast<void **>(&data), len, cudaMemAttachGlobal);
    err = cudaMemPrefetchAsync(data, len, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Just to make extra sure - you're getting the invalid device error only after the `cudaMemAttachGlobal` call, not before, right?

Answer (score 1):

There is know bug confirmed by a NVIDIA employee for Windows system enviroment (see at the [post](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/unified-memory-cuda-beginners/#comment-3388581697) botton, i

On the other hand, there are reports that code like yours work fine under Linux SO, or with Maxwell cards.

I do have the very same [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45492739/cudamemprefetchasync-invalid-device-gp-102-cuda-rc-9) of you, but until now no solutions, even using CUDA 9.0 RC. My advice is to use the regular memory approach for now, since there is more than a year of reporting, but no fix.